# importing SQLite3 in GoLang

Tags: sqlite, go, go-sqlite3

I want to import SQLite3 for my Project

```
import (
    "database/sql"
    _ "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3"
)
```

But this Error happened:

```
could not import github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3 (no required module provides package "github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3")
```

I checked my GOPATH and go module but i couldn't fix it.
thanks for helping me out.

Comment: In these cases I try and re-run `go get -u github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` just to double check the module has the resource (given you're using go modules). Otherwise I would just try to re-install it `go install github.com/mattn/go-sqlite3` and see if that fixes anything.